# What's the difference between getBytes and serialize with String?

Tags: java, string, serialization, redis

Just as the title says, I can't differ `getBytes[]` from `serialization mechanism` with `String`. Below is a test between `getBytes[]` and `serialization mechanism`:

```
    public void testUTF() {

        byte[] data = SerializeUtil.serUTFString(str);
        System.out.println(data.length);
        System.out.println(str.getBytes().length);
    }
```

Here is `SerializeUtil`:

public static byte[] serUTFString(String data) {

```
byte[] result = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArray);
    try {
        oos.writeUTF(data);
        oos.flush();
        result = byteArray.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        oos.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return result;
```

}

When I set `str` to `Redis`, both can work correctly, but `getBytes[]` seems more efficient. Since they all return a `byte array` from `String`, whats's the difference, is `serialization` necessary?

Comment: Surely you discovered that the byte arrays were different lengths and contained different data?

Answer (score 2):

String.getBytes() returns a byte array repersenting the string characters in the default encoding. ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF writes the string length then bytes in modified UTF-8 format, see java.io.DataOutput API.

Comment: +1. `ObjectOutputStream` also writes a stream header for use by `ObjectInputStream.` As the OP isn't calling `writeObject` the use of `ObjectOutputStream` rather than `DataOutputStream` is pointless.

Comment: But what if I replace writeUTF with writeBytes(String) in ObjectOutputStream?